# Mod rewrite allow access to txt file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using polish CMS called Batflat, which .htaccess does not allow access to txt files. I only need to get access to **robots.txt** other txt files may no be accessible.

.htaccess content:

```
# Prevent directory listings
Options -Indexes

# Prevent visitors from viewing files directly
<FilesMatch "\.(sdb|md|html|txt)$">
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

# URL rewrites
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(inc/|themes/|tmp/).*\.(php|html)$ - [F,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I am not familiar with .htaccess - could you help me solve my problem?
Thank you
SK

Comment: "I know nothing about this. Please do this for me." is not a question.

Comment: Ok. You are right, I should have describe many trials to solve this problem.

Comment: Ok. You are right, 
I should have describe many trials to solve this problem, but this may be rather funny - to someone who is familiar with it.
My intention was not to "Please do this for me." but as I know - sometimes it may be a matter of a single code line.

And if someone say: it is impossible. I wont search any further.

Answer (score 0):

I have received answer 5 line should be:

```
<FilesMatch "(\.(sdb|md|html|txt)|(?<!robots.txt))$">
```

Maybe it will solve someone problem.
Greets
SK